# Curl error 77 on 64bit machine

Tags: curl, https, libcurl, rhel, nss

When I run a 32-bit binary on 64-bit RHEL6.2, I get the following output from Curl with return value 0f 77,

```
* About to connect() to 10.30.10.164 port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 10.30.10.164... * connected
* Connected to 10.30.10.164 (10.30.10.164) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: /etc/pki/nssdb
* Unable to initialize NSS database
* NSS error -5977
* Closing connection #0
* Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

I did a little research and found that nss library has [problems](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=751694).
My requirement is to run a 32bit binary on 64-bit machine that uses libcurl dynamic library. Anybody has any workaround to achieve this on RHEL 6.2 x64 machine?

I can provide more details on request..

Language : C
Platform : Linux (RHEL 6.2 x64)

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Could you try building CURL with a different SSL provider? CURL currently supports several including CyaSSL, NSS, OpenSSL, PolarSSL, GnuTLS, and axTLS.

Comment: ya that would solve the problem. but i did one lazy work around, just simply copied libcurl3 from 32-bit machine(RHEL5.5, compiled here) to 64-bit(RHEL6.2, target system) machine and linked dynamic libs. It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I did one lazy work around, just simply copied libcurl3 from 32-bit machine(RHEL5.5, compiled here) to 64-bit(RHEL6.2, target system) machine and linked libcurl dynamic lib. It worked :)